# Deposition of Nb on SiO2 wafer (Z-Cut)

Tags: metal, organosilicon-compounds

I am trying to sputter $\ce{Nb}$ on $\ce{SiO2}$ Z-Cut wafers (quartz crystal).  I was wondering if $\ce{Nb}$ will stick well to the surface of the wafer.

I've routinely deposited $\ce{Nb}$ on $\ce{Si}$ wafers but have never done so on quartz crystal wafers.

Comment: Worried about Nb "sticking" to SiO2 or ["reacting"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0038110178903350) with SiO2?